# Configuring VLAN-based priority/QOS on Brocade NOS?

Tags: routing, vlan, qos, brocade

I would like to do QoS based on port-based VLAN traffic on a Brocade VDX67xx series router running NOS 4.1.

Just need a way to say, "traffic on VLAN 100 has a higher priority ingress/egress than vlan 200."

I am not seeing an obvious way to do this. I know in the past, on Cisco devices, you can assign a priority to a VLAN interface.

I've combed google, and the manual and must be missing something. The `qos` command in the configuration doesn't seem like anything I need either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it can be done in this way.
First select the traffic to mark:

```
sw0(config)# ip access-list extended acl1

sw0(conf-ipacl-ext)# permit ip any any vlan 100
```

Then link the ACL with a class-map:

```
sw0(config)# class-map class1

sw0(config-classmap)# match access-group acl1
```

Then assign the CoS value:

```
sw0(config)# policy-map policy1

sw0(config-policymap)# class class1

sw0(config-policymap-class)# set cos 3
```

As a last step apply the ACL to an RBridge:

```
sw0(config)# qos service-policy in policy1

sw0(config-service-policy-in/policy1)# attach rbridge-id add 10
```